# Using Total Expectation Theorem to derive the Total Variance Formula

Tags: probability

*This might be an elementary question. However, I am confused for several days and I try to understand the underlying mechanics as fully as possible.

It is known that E[X] = E[E[X|Y]].

Now, let us consider the random sum of N i.i.d Random Variables with mean $\mu$ and variance $\delta^2$.

Let $X = \sum_{1}^{N} X_i$, $E[X] = \mu E[N]; E[X|N=n] = n\mu$

Now, $Var(X) = E[(X-\mu E[N])^2]$ and

$Var(X|N=n) = E[(X-n\mu)^2] = E[X^2] - n^2\mu^2 = Var(\sum_{1}^{n}X_i) = n\delta^2$

Then by $E[(X-\mu E[N])^2] = E[E[(X-\mu E[N])^2]|N=n] = E[Var(X)|N=n] = Var(X) =  n\delta^2$, we have finished the proof(which is clearly wrong).

However, I cannot see where I had gone wrong. Can someone point out the misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to see what went wrong, you first have to know what a correct computation looks like.

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}[X]
&= \operatorname{E}[(X - \operatorname{E}[X])^2] \tag{definition} \\
&= \operatorname{E}[X^2] - \operatorname{E}[X]^2 \tag{alternate form} \\
&= \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[X^2 \mid N]] - \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[X \mid N]]^2 \tag{total expectation} \\
&= \operatorname{E}\left[\operatorname{E}\left[\Bigl(\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\Bigr)^2 \mid N\right]\right] - \operatorname{E}[\mu N]^2 \tag{definition}\\
&= \operatorname{E}\left[\operatorname{E}\left[ \sum_{i=1}^N X_i^2 + 2 \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^N X_i X_j \mid N\right] \right] - \mu^2 \operatorname{E}[N]^2 \tag{expansion} \\
&= \operatorname{E}\left[N \operatorname{E}[X_1^2] + N(N-1)\operatorname{E}[X_1]^2\right] - \mu^2 \operatorname{E}[N]^2 \tag{$X_i$ are iid} \\
&= \operatorname{E}[N](\operatorname{Var}[X_1] + \operatorname{E}[X_1]^2) + \operatorname{E}[N(N-1)] \mu^2 - \mu^2 \operatorname{E}[N]^2 \tag{algebra}\\
&= \operatorname{E}[N](\sigma^2 + \mu^2) + (\operatorname{E}[N^2] - \operatorname{E}[N])\mu^2 - \mu^2 \operatorname{E}[N]^2 \\
&= \operatorname{E}[N]\sigma^2 + (\operatorname{Var}[N] + \operatorname{E}[N]^2)\mu^2 - \mu^2 \operatorname{E}[N]^2 \\
&= \operatorname{E}[N]\sigma^2 + \operatorname{Var}[N]\mu^2.
\end{align}$$
Where did you go wrong?  Well, this statement
$$\operatorname{E}[(X - \mu \operatorname{E}[N])^2] = \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[(X - \mu \operatorname{E}[N])^2] \mid N = n]$$ is incorrect.  This would be analogous to writing $$\operatorname{E}[A] = \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[A] \mid B],$$ which is not what the law of total expectation says; it says $$\operatorname{E}[A] = \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[A \mid B]].$$  So your statement should read
$$\operatorname{E}[(X - \mu \operatorname{E}[N])^2] = \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[(X - \mu \operatorname{E}[N])^2 \mid N]].$$  And this is where we discover the error in your reasoning, since this equation is also false, but for a different reason.  The problem is that $$\operatorname{E}[(X - \mu \operatorname{E}[N])^2 \mid N] = \operatorname{E}[(X - \mu N)^2 \mid N],$$ because given $N$, the expectation $\operatorname{E}[N] = N$.

To illustrate further, consider the following thought experiment.  For each $j = 1, 2, \ldots, m$, you generate a realization $N = n_j$ from $N$, which tells you how many of the $X_i$ to generate.  Then again for each $j$, you generate $n_j$ of the $X_i$ and total them to get a realization $X^*_j$, and the sample $(X^*_1, X^*_2, \ldots, X^*_m)$ represents the distribution of $X$.  Then the sample variance of these realizations of $X$ is an unbiased estimator of the total variance of $X$.  But this sample variance is calculated as $$\widehat {\operatorname{Var}}[X] = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{j=1}^m (X^*_j - \bar X^*)^2.$$  Note that this calculation uses the sample mean of the realizations, which is $\bar X^*$.  Although each realization $X^*_j$ corresponds to some randomly generated $n_j$ that are in general different for each $j$, the variance is calculated with the overall sample mean.

But what would it mean to compute $$\operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[(X - \mu \operatorname{E}[N])^2 \mid N]]?$$  This corresponds to a different process:  for each realization $N = n_j$, you would compute the quantity $\mu n_j$ where $\mu$ is the common mean of the iid variables $X_i$.  Then you would subtract this from the realization $X^*_j$ for each $j$, and square it.  In other words, $$\operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[(X - \mu \operatorname{E}[N])^2 \mid N]] \approx \frac{1}{m} \sum_{j=1}^m (X^*_j - \mu n_j)^2.$$  And this is very much not what we want, because there is a component of the total variance of $X$ that is lost, which is the variability of each $X^*_j$ that is attributable to the variation in $N$, rather than the variability within each $X_i$.  In other words,
$$\operatorname{Var}[X] = \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[(X - \operatorname{E}[X])^2 \mid N]] \ne \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[(X - \mu \operatorname{E}[N])^2 \mid N]] = \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{Var}[X \mid N]].$$  You would think that you can use the law of total expectation to write $\operatorname{E}[X] = \mu \operatorname{E}[N]$ in the second step but you cannot, because the *entire* quantity $(X - \operatorname{E}[X])^2$ is conditioned on $N$ in the first step, not just $\operatorname{E}[X]$.  As a result, you have only retained the "within group" variation $\operatorname{E}[\operatorname{Var}[X \mid N]]$ that represents the variability of the $X_i$ around the group mean $\mu N$, and have lost the quantity $\operatorname{Var}[\operatorname{E}[X \mid N]]$, which we call the "between groups" variance that accounts for the variation due to $N$.

To further your understanding, try performing a simulation of the following model:

$$N \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n = 12, p = 2/3) \\
X_i \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(\lambda = 4), \quad i \in \{1, 2, \ldots, N\}.
$$
Here, $\lambda$ is a rate parameter so the conditional mean $\operatorname{E}[X_i \mid N] = 1/\lambda = 1/4$.  Then it is easy to show that $$X \mid N \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(N, \lambda)$$ where the parametrization is by shape and rate.  So rather than generating $n_j$ iid exponential random variables, you can generate a single gamma random variable $X^*_j$ with shape $n_j$.  Of course, if $n_j = 0$, then $X^*_j = 0$.
We can see that we should have $$\operatorname{E}[X] = np/\lambda = 2, \\ \operatorname{Var}[X] = np/\lambda^2 + np(1-p)/\lambda^2 = 2/3.$$

Here is a short table I calculated for $m = 10$ simulations:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
j & n_j & X^*_j = (X \mid N = n_j) & n_j/\lambda & (X^*_j - n_j/\lambda)^2  \\
\hline
 1 & 12 & 1.92252 & 3. & 1.16097 \\
 2 & 9 & 1.32009 & 2.25 & 0.864737 \\
 3 & 9 & 3.89578 & 2.25 & 2.70858 \\
 4 & 9 & 2.59906 & 2.25 & 0.121846 \\
 5 & 10 & 2.82667 & 2.5 & 0.106714 \\
 6 & 7 & 2.64605 & 1.75 & 0.802913 \\
 7 & 5 & 1.83194 & 1.25 & 0.33866 \\
 8 & 9 & 2.58618 & 2.25 & 0.113014 \\
 9 & 8 & 2.11105 & 2. & 0.0123324 \\
 10 & 7 & 1.23446 & 1.75 & 0.265778 \\
\end{array}$$
Now, compute the total sample mean and sample variance with the third column.    In my case, I get $\bar X = 2.29738$ and $s^2 = 0.623086$.  Now compute the mean of the last column to get $\operatorname{E}[\operatorname{Var}[X \mid N]] \approx 0.649555$.  In this case, these values are similar but with more simulations, you will see they begin to look different.  For $m = 10^5$, I get $\bar X = 2.00048$, $s^2 = 0.669821$, and the last column has mean $0.503621$, which deviates from $s^2$.  This discrepancy is especially apparent even for small samples when the between-group variance is large compared to the within-group variance; e.g., try instead
$$N \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n = 12, p = 9/10), \\ X_i \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu = 1, \sigma^2 = 1/100), \\
X \mid N \sim \operatorname{Normal}(N, N/100).$$  This gives a table that looks like this:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
j & n_j & X^*_j = (X \mid N = n_j) & \mu n_j & (X^*_j - \mu n_j)^2  \\
\hline
 1 & 11 & 10.9336 & 11 & 0.00441132 \\
 2 & 11 & 10.8612 & 11 & 0.0192544 \\
 3 & 12 & 12.4073 & 12 & 0.165867 \\
 4 & 12 & 11.2885 & 12 & 0.506161 \\
 5 & 9 & 8.66697 & 9 & 0.110909 \\
 6 & 11 & 11.0019 & 11 & 0.0000036715 \\
 7 & 11 & 10.763 & 11 & 0.0561849 \\
 8 & 10 & 9.99503 & 10 & 0.0000247168 \\
 9 & 11 & 10.9835 & 11 & 0.000271241 \\
 10 & 10 & 9.86158 & 10 & 0.0191596 \\
\end{array}$$
Right away, you can see there is a problem.  The sample mean and variance are $$\bar X = 10.6763, \quad s^2 = 0.982748,$$ but the mean of the last column is tiny, $0.0882247$, because the within-group variance is small compared to the between-group variance.

Comment: A legend answer

Answer (score 1):

Using the law of total variance,
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(X)&=\mathsf{E}[\operatorname{Var}(X\mid N)]+\operatorname{Var}(\mathsf{E}[X\mid N]) \\
&=\mathsf{E} N\delta^2+\operatorname{Var}(N\mu)\\
&=\delta^2\mathsf{E}N+\mu^2\operatorname{Var}(N).
\end{align}